# how can I retrieve data from Excel file *.xlsx by using php code

Tags: php, excel

my code, it can only using with excel *.xls file

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
```

how can i connect to excel *.xlsx file.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example for  you. It written using simple php code. May it helps you
Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B78cEc-NJNP8Ui10Z2lEMEkxWkU/edit?usp=sharing) to get the program.
To download the zip : click menu File, then choose download

Comment: this file zip, after i download it, cannot extract, why ? can u help me

Comment: @heso dente when I try to extract this zip file its need to give password. pleas give the password

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget that it has a password. Here's the password `okierie` (It's my friend's project) :D